# Clicking mouse once repeats it many times TASM

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

I'm working on an Assembly project (TASM and DOSBox) that utilizes the mouse.
When the user clicks on a certain area on the screen, a certain message is printed.

My problem is that the computer continues to print the message as long as the mouse button is pressed (3 or 4 times each click).

I tried saving the last button pressed and prevent printing the message if the same button was pressed twice in a row as you can see in the code below but it doesn't seem to work. I also understood that there's a way to get a button **release** info but I also couldn't seem to get it to work.

Anyone have an idea of what I can do to fix this or a different way? Thanks.

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 0f500h

    mouse_last_button dw 1  ;holds the value of last mouse button clicked
    mouse_button dw 0       ;holds the value of mouse button clicked
    counter dw ?
    x_clicked dw ?
    y_clicked dw ?
    half_button dw 9
    arr_length dw 76
    clear_x dw 229
    clear_y dw 137

CODESEG

;================PROCEDURES================
proc setGraphic
    ;sets graphic mode
    mov ax, 13h
    int 10h
    ret
endp setGraphic
;-----------------
proc initMouse
    ;initializes mouse
    mov ax, 0
    int 33h ;resets mouse
    mov ax, 1
    int 33h ;shows pointer
    ret
endp initMouse
;-----------------
proc initImage
    ;imports keyboard bitmap
    mov [BmpLeft],0
    mov [BmpTop],99
    mov [BmpColSize], 320
    mov [BmpRowSize] ,101
    mov dx,offset SmallPicName
    call OpenShowBmp
    ret
endp initImage
;-----------------
proc getMouseClick
    mov ax, [mouse_button] ;stores the value of the last state of the mouse
    mov [mouse_last_button], ax
    mov ax,3
    int 33h ;gets mouse information
    shr cx, 1   ;halves the x position value since the interrupt returns double

    mov [mouse_button],bx   ;saves the click's button, x and y position
    mov [x_clicked],cx  
    mov [y_clicked],dx
    ret
endp getMouseClick
;-----------------
proc checkMouseButton
    ret
endp checkMouseButton
;-----------------
proc checkXR
    ;check if click is not more than 9 pixels right to the center (of the button)
    mov bx, offset x_arr
    add bx,[counter]
    mov ax,[bx]
    add ax,[half_button]
    ret
endp checkXR
;-----------------
proc checkXL
    ;check if click is not more than 9 pixels left to the center
    mov ax,[bx]
    sub ax,[half_button]
    ret
endp checkXL
;-----------------
proc checkYT
    ;check if click is not more than 9 pixels above the center
    mov bx, offset y_arr
    add bx,[counter]
    mov ax,[bx]
    sub ax,[half_button]
    ret
endp checkYT
;-----------------
proc checkYB
    ;check if click is not more than 9 pixels below the center
    mov ax,[bx]
    add ax,[half_button]
    ret
endp checkYB
;-----------------
proc printLetter
    ;prints the character at button that was clicked
    mov bx, offset letter_arr   
    mov ax,[counter]
    shr ax,1    ;halves counter since letter_arr is byte sized and counter is word sized
    add bx,ax
    mov dx, [bx]
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    ret
endp printLetter
;-----------------
;================PROCEDURES================

start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

    call setGraphic ;sets graphic mode
    call initMouse ;initializes mouse
    call initImage  ;displays keyboard's image

    mov cx, [arr_length] ;iterates over all of the buttons in the keyboard until one matches a click's location
    mov [counter],cx

mouseLoop:
    call getMouseClick

    mov ax, [mouse_button]      ;waits for the user to click left mouse button
    cmp ax, 1
    jne doLoop
    cmp ax,[mouse_last_button]  ;if button pressed before is the same as the current one, wait for another press
    je mouseLoop

    call checkXR    ;checks X right
    cmp [x_clicked],ax
    ja searchAgain

    call checkXL    ;checks X left
    cmp [x_clicked],ax
    jb searchAgain

    call checkYT    ;checks Y top
    cmp [y_clicked],ax
    jb searchAgain

    call checkYB    ;checks Y bottom
    cmp [y_clicked],ax
    jb writeLetter

searchAgain:
    ;precedes to the next button in the array 
    mov cx,[counter]
    dec [counter]
    cmp cx,0
    jnz mouseLoop
    jmp doLoop

writeLetter:
    call printLetter    ;prints the letter found
    call initImage  ;restarts the keyboard image
    mov ax, 1
    int 33h ;shows pointer

doLoop:
    ;starts iterating over arrays again
    mov cx,[arr_length]
    mov [counter],cx
    jmp mouseLoop

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Another thing to mention: when I set

```
    cmp ax,[mouse_last_button]
    jne mouseLoop
```

to `je` (as it actually should be), nothing happens at all.

Comment: Where are all of those variables declared? Did you perhaps declare any of them as a byte instead of word by mistake?

Comment: Nope. Both are word sized with starting values of 1 for `mouse_last_button` and 0 for `mouse_button`

Comment: This seems awfully similar to a question a few days back: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870777/why-cant-i-get-different-mouse-clicks-coordinates-twice-assembly

Comment: As michael points out we don't know how you declared the data at the labels (and their size). It would help if you made this an [mcve] and show *complete* code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Update: the "wait for release" loop advice is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
I deleted:

```
    cmp ax,[mouse_last_button]
    je mouseLoop
```

and added:

```
waitForRelease: 
    call getMouseClick
    mov ax,[mouse_button]
    cmp ax,0
    jne waitForRelease
```

right after `writeLetter` which enters a loop that waits for the user to release the mouse button, than continues.